# How does the set difference property work in set theory?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

[image]

This is my work so far on this problem, but the cases with the "..." I am unsure if I am able to go from $x \in (B \cup C) \implies x \in ((B \cup C) \setminus A)$ (Case 1.1). I know you are able to remove $\setminus A$ with the set difference property, but is there a way to add complements in universal generization? All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Case 1.1, you know more than $x \in B$.  You know that $x \in B \setminus A$, which means that $x \in B$ *and also* $x \notin A$.  Use that to complete the case -- if $x \in B$ and $x \notin A$, then $x \in (B \cup C) \setminus A$.

Similarly for the remaining cases.

Comment: Yes I just noticed this took some time looking over. Thank you!